# How much blood do we have when the heart first starts to beat?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology, cardiology, development

How much blood do we have when the heart beats for the first time?

It should be between the third and fourth week of embryonic life.

Comment: Note: there is a heart "beat" but no pumping at 3-4 weeks. The blood vessels and chambers of the heart have not developed. The "beat" is just electrical activity in cells that will eventually become part of the heart.

Comment: From your comment I guess we don't even have blood at 4 weeks